# clearInterval function not actually clearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `div` completes one round from left to right and right to left scrolling but gets stuck in the `scrollBack()` function. The program does execute the `clearInterval()` statement at the desired event but it doesn't actually clear the interval. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var backint = null;

function scrollForward() {
  if ($("#foo").scrollLeft() != $("#foo").width()) {
    $("#foo").scrollLeft($("#foo").scrollLeft() + 1);
  } else {
    backint = setInterval(scrollBack, 5);
  }
}

function scrollBack() {
  if ($("#foo").scrollLeft() != 0) {
    $("#foo").scrollLeft($("#foo").scrollLeft() - 1);
  } else if ($("#foo").scrollLeft() == 0) {
    clearInterval(backint);
  }
}
```

Comment: please share html code. Thanks

Comment: I might be wrong but I'm not sure that backint used in the scrollBack function is understood properly by the javascript since it seems to be a local variable. Try to initiate it as a global

Comment: if($("#foo").scrollLeft()  > 0){  ... ? and make the else if just an else

Comment: The point of the interval seems a little moot as you could just use `animate()` on the `left` property of the element.

Comment: Animate works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better do with 
[`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) as [*Rory McCrossan*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792526/clearinterval-function-not-actually-clearing#comment68807440_40792526) suggested because that `setInterval` reimplements existing thing and not necessarily better:

```js
var foo = $("#container"),
  bar = $("#foo"),
  scrollSize = bar.width() - foo.width();;

function scrollForward() {
  console.log('forward', foo.scrollLeft(), bar.width() - foo.width());
  if (foo.scrollLeft() != scrollSize) {
    foo.animate({
      scrollLeft: scrollSize + 'px'
    });
  }
}

function scrollBack() {
  console.log('back', foo.scrollLeft(), scrollSize);
  if (foo.scrollLeft() === scrollSize) {
    foo.animate({
      scrollLeft: '0px'
    });
  }
}

foo.on("click", scrollForward);
foo.on("dblclick", scrollBack);
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 410px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 50px;
}
#foo {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 1300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="foo">Click to scroll right. Double-click to scroll left.</div>
</div>
```